# Relation between applied forces and acceleration

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, angular-velocity

[image]

How do we find the magnitude of linear and angular acceleration with a given system like this picture above?
I don't understand the relation between a force on the center of mass and one on the edge.

Would applying a force on the edge, effect the total linear acceleration?

(you can consider the rod floating in space)

Comment: For questions about acceleration, motion, velocity, work, one must always first specify a frame of reference, because all these quantities depend on it. Sometimes there's a specific choice suggested by the problem (but still arbitrary), sometimes several. So the first question is: in which frame of reference do you want to examine the problem?

Comment: @pglpm in the problem i have, its not given what you ask me. but maybe for an inertial observer?

Comment: You're always free to choose the frame you want. If the problem asks for a specific one, you can even work in a different frame first and then transform your solution into the other frame. Inertial frames are often convenient, but not always.

Comment: Hard subject, can be many interpretations. As @FrankLau noticed, situation depends on which pivot point do we take as a reference point. Secondly, even if we take com as a pivot point, still situation depends on rod elasticity. If, say rod is very elastic and thin - then edge forces can bend it into V (parabola-shaped) object with a net torque greater than zero about center. Or it may bend a little (some torque) and then move forward aftewards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear acceleration requires a **net force** to act on an object. This acceleration is then given by $\text{N2L}$:

$$F_{net}=ma$$

For angular acceleration to occur, a **net torque** needs to act on an object. This acceleration is then given by $\text{N2L}$:

$$\tau_{net}=I\alpha$$

For your object there's a net upward force of $F$ ($=2F-F$) acting, so the object will accelerate upwardly.

But there's no net torque: you can calculate the torque about any point and it always yields $0$.

Now if we were to remove the right hand side upward force $F$ there would be a net torque. For instance calculated *about* the centre point, the net torque would be:

$$\tau_{net}=\frac{L}{2}F$$

where $L$ is the total length of the bar.

The bar would then experience clockwise angular acceleration.

Objects can undergo linear and angular acceleration at once. For instance increase the left hand side upward force from $F$ to $2F$: there's now a net upward force as well as net torque acting on the bar.

Comment: In the original question, if we take the left end(or right end) as the pivot then the net torque is not 0. How to explain this?

Comment: thanks! it helped a lot.